# AIOHTTP:TypeError: index() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Tags: async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp, pytest-aiohttp

```
from aiohttp import web
import aiohttp
from settings import config
import asyncio
import psycopg2 as p
import json
import aiopg

import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def fetch(client):
    async with client.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1') as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        return await resp.json()

async def index():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        html = await fetch(client)
        return web.Response(html)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(index())
```

this is my views.py

```
from aiohttp import web
from routes import setup_routes
from settings import config

app = web.Application()
setup_routes(app)

web.run_app(app,port=9090)
```

main.py

```
from views import index

def setup_routes(app):
    app.router.add_get('/', index)
```

and here is my routes.py

but when ever i tried to fire the url of localhost:9090 i just get an internal server 500 error
saying

```
TypeError: index() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

but t i can print the json in the terminal but couldnt  fire the same as web response in the browser i dont know what is wrong in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `index` coroutine is a [handler](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#aiohttp-web-handler), so it must accept a single positional argument, which will receive a [`Request`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#aiohttp.web.Request) instance. For example:

```
async def index(request):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        html = await fetch(client)
        return web.Response(html)
```

The `loop.run_until_complete(index())` at the top-level of `views.py` is unnecessary and won't work once `index()` is defined correctly.

Comment: but whenever i tried to run the server i cant stop the server and cant acess the page its saying me that the page cannot be loaded ,can i know why and how can we fix the issue??

Answer (score 1):

Your `index()` async function should accept `request` argument to be a web-handler compatible.